# C++ Robust Model Fitting Library

Tags: c++, ransac

Often when I need to perform model fitting I find myself looking for a decent C++ library to do this. There is the RANSAC implementation in [MRPT](http://reference.mrpt.org/svn/classmrpt_1_1math_1_1_model_search.html), but I was wondering if there are alternatives available.

To give an example for the type of problems I would like to solve: For a set $A$ of (approx 500) 3D point pairs $(a, b)$ I would like to find the Isometry transform $T$, which maps the points onto each other so that $|(a - Tb)| < \epsilon$. I would like to get the largest subset of $A$ for a given $\epsilon$. Alternatively I guess I could have the subset size fixed and ask for the lowest $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PCL](http://www.pointclouds.org/) has a nice C++ templated [RANSAC library](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__sample__consensus.html) which can solve your problem.

If you feel, PCL is too big of a dependency, then using [umeyama](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__Geometry__Module.html#gab3f5a82a24490b936f8694cf8fef8e60) function in [Eigen's](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) geometry module is probably the easiest way towards a working solution for your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't looked at PCL. The umeyama function would do what I want in the absence of outliers, but usually doesn't work very well if there are any.